# Is it possible to change the Enter key function for just one cell?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, enter

I have a cell (=$C$4) on a worksheet that is referenced in multiple formulas. I am using it as an end-user input cell.

I am trying to avoid selecting next cell after Enter is pressed so users can input values, hit Enter, see the results, then if needed, replace the contents with new values in the cell and hit Enter again to see different results without having to arrow-up or click on the cell again.

Is there a way to change the function of Enter for just this cell or is anyone aware of another work-around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sheet protection to do that:

- Unlock cell C4 in the *Format Cell* dialog (in the *Protection* tab)
- Make sure all other cells are locked (which they are be default)
- Right click the worksheet name, click *Protect sheet*, uncheck *Select locked cells* and press OK

Done!

If for some reason this is not applicable, you can use this macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C4")) Is Nothing Then
        Me.Range("C4").Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

You need to place this code in the worksheet module of your worksheet. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd> to activate the Visual Basic Editor, double click on the worksheet in the tree view on the top left and paste your code in the main window!

Comment: Protection works very well for this. However, when the formula is calculated I want the users to be able to copy the values out of the formula cells (which I need to be locked and hidden).

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar once by implementing a VBA subroutine. I think that the signature of the sub is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

All you need to do in the body is check if the current cell is the cell below C4 then select C4, otherwise do nothing.